# Müser engine and solar conversion efficiency

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, carnot-cycle

I found in many reference a derivation of the maximal conversion efficiency from solar power to work with the so-called that I found dubious (see for instance [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Abderrahmane_Belghachi/publication/283086224_Theoretical_Calculation_of_the_Efficiency_Limit_for_Solar_Cells/links/562a05bc08aef25a243fc183.pdf)).

It usually goes like this. Let us consider the sun at $ T_\odot $ , an absorber at $ T_A$ and a sink $T_0$. A converter is performing cycles between the absorber and the sink.

The power is extracted from the heat flow supplied by the absorber and is limited by the Carnot efficiency

$$ \dot{W}=\dot{Q_A} \left( 1 - \frac{T_0}{T_A} \right) $$

The heat flow $\dot{Q_A}$ supplied by the absorber to the converter corresponds to the power difference between the input power $J_{E,in}=A\frac{\Omega_\odot}{\pi}\sigma T_\odot ^4$ and the radiated power $J_{E,rad}=A\frac{\Omega_A}{\pi}\sigma T_A ^4$, where $A$ is the surface of the absorber, $\Omega_\odot$ is the solid angle of the sun and $\Omega_A$ the solid angle of emission.

$$ \dot{Q_A} = A\frac{\Omega_\odot}{\pi}\sigma T_\odot ^4 - A\frac{\Omega_A}{\pi}\sigma T_A ^4 = J_{E,in} \left( 1 -\frac{\Omega_A}{\Omega_\odot} \frac{T_A^4}{T_\odot^4} \right)$$

and the overall efficiency is estimated as

$$\frac{\dot{W}}{J_{E,in}} =\left( 1 - \frac{\Omega_A}{\Omega_\odot}\frac{T_A^4}{T_\odot^4} \right)\left( 1 - \frac{T_0}{T_A} \right)
$$

What bothers me is that the Carnot efficiency is obtained when the entropy flow from the heat source is $\dot{S}_A=T_A \dot{Q_A}$. However, an entropy balance on the absorber gives
$$
\dot{S}_A= \frac{4}{3} A\frac{\Omega_\odot}{\pi}\sigma T_\odot ^3 - \frac{4}{3} A\frac{\Omega_A}{\pi}\sigma T_A ^3 = \frac{4}{3}  \frac{J_{E,in}}{T_\odot} \left( 1 -\frac{\Omega_A}{\Omega_\odot} \frac{T_A^3}{T_\odot^3} \right) \neq T_A \dot{Q_A}$$.

So it seems to me you can't simply plug together the absorber and a Carnot engine - the estimation of $\dot{Q_A}=J_{E,in}-J_{E,rad}$ is wrong, it should actually be $\dot{Q_A}+\dot{W_A}=J_{E,in}-J_{E,rad}$ and $\dot{Q_A} =T_A \times(J_{S,in}-J_{S,rad}) $.

Am I making a mistake somewhere ? Or what is that thing about people using the Müser efficiency ?

Comment: $\dot{S}_A$ is the rate of entropy generation of the universe when heat flows from sun to absorber. Why do you expect it to equal entropy flow out of absorber, $T_A\dot{Q}_A$? Also remember that in irreversible processes entropy is not a conserved quantity.

Comment: @Deep Maybe what I'm missing is what is $J_S = \frac{4}{3}\sigma T^3$. I thought it was the entropy taken in / out the system during the absorption / emission of a black body radiation. Is that incorrect ?

Comment: $J_S$ is indeed the entropy flux term. The net difference between all the entropy fluxes gives you entropy generation in the universe.